# Removing a random number of columns from a matrix

Tags: matlab

I need to take away a random number of columns from an arbitrarily large matrix, I've put my attempt below, but I'm certain that there is a better way.

```
function new = reduceMatrices(original, colsToTakeAway)

a = colsToTakeAway(1);
b = colsToTakeAway(2);
c = colsToTakeAway(3);

x = original(1:a-1);
y = original(a+1:b-1);
z = original(b+1:c-1);

if c == size(original, 2);
    new = [x,y,z];
elseif (c+1) == size(original, 2);
    new = [x,y,z,c+1]
else
new = [x,y,z,c+1:size(original, 2)];

end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one approach.  First, generate a row vector of random numbers with `numcols` elements, where `numcols` is the number of columns in the original matrix:

```
rc = rand(1,numcols)
```

Next make a vector of `1`s and `0`s from this, for example

```
lv = rc>0.75
```

which will produce something like

```
 0 1 1 0 1
```

and you can use Matlab's logical indexing feature to write

```
original(:,lv)
```

which will return only those columns of `original` which correspond to the `1`s in `lv`.

It's not entirely clear from your question how you want to make the vector of column selections, but this should give you some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

```
function newM = reduceMatrices(original, colsToTakeAway)

   % define the columns to keep := cols \ colsToTakeAway
   colsToKeep = setdiff(1:size(original,2), colsToTakeAway);

   newM = original(:, colsToKeep);

end
```